# How to print the "+" character on the console screen using the arrow keys?

Tags: c

```
first starting point -->+
                    +  + <--last destination
                    +  + 
                    +..+
```

I want to write a program that uses the arrow keys to place the + character on the current position of the cursor on the screen every time these keys are touched, thus allowing drawing on the screen.
The key that activates and deactivates the drawing feature should be the space key; In other words, drawing / not drawing on the screen is adjusted by means of the space key.

The spacebar is a mode selector, it determines that the cursor can be moved freely without any typing on the screen, or the + character will be pressed to the current position of the cursor while navigating with the arrow keys. Spacebar does not need to be used every time the arrow keys are pressed!

After pressing the spacebar, the direction keys can be used many times and as many times as necessary, so that the + symbol can be pressed on the screen as many times as necessary, or the cursor can be moved freely as required without writing anything on the screen. To put it further: Spacebar was pressed (drawing mode activated, + typed where the cursor is, red + at the top left), then down arrow, down arrow, down arrow; the spacebar has been pressed (no drawing, ie free travel mode activated); then right arrow, right arrow, right arrow; spacebar was pressed (drawing mode activated again, + typed where the cursor was at that moment, red + at the bottom right); If the up arrow and up arrow are used, an output like the one below will appear on the screen.

The esc key will be used to exit the program.

I got this output with the code below, maybe I may need to use arrays, but I don't know how.

I can only get this printout:

```
+++ 
+++++ 
+++++
```

My codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    
    
        int main() {
            char button;
            
             while(1){           
                  button= getch(); 
                  if(button==77){ 
                     printf("+");
                     button= getch();
                   }
                   else if(button==75){
                        printf("+"); 
                         button= getch();
                   }
                   else if(button==72){
                        printf("+");
                         button= getch();
                   } 
                   else if(button==80){   
                         printf("+\n");  
                         button= getch();
                  }
              }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Did you consider using the ncurses library?

Comment: Do not use `button==75` and so on. Use `button == 'K'`, `button == 'H'`, and `button == 'P'`.

Comment: The C standard does not provide any facilities for moving the cursor around the display. If you are on a Unix or Unix-like system, you may have [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) available, and you will need to learn that or a similar facility. Alternately, you can learn the escape sequences for the terminal you are targeting. Note that when writing them, you will need to flush the output or disable buffering on the output stream.

Comment: When I create it with letters, I can't move any way on the console screen. And I have to code it without using an additional library.

Comment: ANSI escape codes should be available on most VT100-compatible terminals

Comment: Did you mean the goto command?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
    int x=30,y=10;
    char c;
    gotoxy(x,y);
    printf("+");
    while(1){
            
            
            c=getch();
            if(c==77){
                x++;
               }
               if(c==75){
                x--;
               }
              if(c==72){
                y--;
               } 
               if(c==80){
                y++;
               }
               if(c==27){
                break;
               }
               gotoxy(x,y);
               printf("*");
           }
    getch();

       
   
           
            return 0;
        } 
        int gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
   int gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coordinate;
    coordinate.X = x;
    coordinate.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coordinate);
    return 0;
}
```